# I want to add a value to an existing XML object/tree in python

Tags: python, xml

As of now I import an existing XML-tempalte:

```
from lxml import etree
xmlTemplate = etree.parse('linux_inv.xml')
xml = xmlTemplate.getroot()
```

XML-template (simplified):

```
<InventoryData>
<general/>
    <Table Name="InvMain">
        <Column Name="ID">0</Column>
    </Table>
    <Table Name="InvComputer">
        <Column Name="Hostname"></Column>
    </Table>
</InventoryData>
```

Now I want to add a string value to the table with Name="InvComputer" and the column with Name="Hostname". Something like that:

```
xml[InventoryData][Table@Name="InvComputer"][Column@Name="Hostname"].text = "jumpServer01"
```

Sadly I can't find it that way. Only iterating over the whole xml tree and checking every attribute along the way.

I am working with python 2.7.3 and I don't care which xml implementation is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using XPath expressions. To get the required node, you may use this code

```
nodes = xmlTemplate .xpath('/InventoryData/Table[@Name="InvComputer"]/Column[@Name="Hostname"]')
```

You may also check out [this documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) about xpath in lxml and [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) about xpath syntax.